# Render JSONB fields in unittests

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have the following table declaration

```
    class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        x = Column(JSONB)
        y = Column(JSONB)
```

This works like a charm when trying to create the table with Base.metadata.create_all(engine) where engine is a postgresql engine, but the problem comes when trying to use sqlite as an engine 'sqlite:///:memory'.

I know that this is happening because sqlite doesn't support JSONB fields, but in my specific case I must use JSONB (that's because later we are doing some searches after json elements, and we can't use TEXT or String Columns instead because we use the 'Table' as base class for other things, so we should stick to JSONB fields).

The unittests are the biggest problem, because we cannot switch to a postgresql connection to not create dependencies.

Does anyone knows any way around this problem?

Comment: Some of them yes. The already built infrastructure was developed around postgresql. I'm actually trying to extend some base classes to acomodate some new columns to store that JSON info (the content will be used in the future to filter for some results). I'm aware that a possible option is this sens would be to have a Json field and cast it to JSONB in order to be able to do the filtering more easly but that is really slow.